# Custom cursor on ASP.NET ImageButton control hover

Tags: asp.net, image, cursor, imagebutton

To draw a sort of map, I have a table and need to dynamically add one ImageButton in each cell. So far, no problem. But then I have to change all the controls' onmouseover cursors when one of them is clicked. More precisely, I would like the cursor to become the clicked ImageButton's ImageUrl, which is a png format.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // Create new row and add it to the table.
        TableRow line = new TableRow();
        _DomainMap.Rows.Add(line);
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.ID = "_Case"+i+j;
            ImageButton domain_item = new ImageButton();
            domain_item.CssClass = "domainitem";
            domain_item.ImageUrl = "~/Images/empty.png";
            domain_item.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(_DomainItem_Click);
            domain_item.ID = "_Image" + i + j;
            cell.Controls.Add(domain_item);
            line.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
    }
}

protected void _DomainItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeCursor(((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl);
}

protected void ChangeCursor(String cursor_path)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _DomainMap.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _DomainMap.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            ImageButton imgb = ((ImageButton)_DomainMap.FindControl("_Image" + i + j));
            imgb.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "setcursor(" + imgb + ", " + imgb.ImageUrl + ");");
        }
    }
}
```

And the "setcursor" javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setcursor(control, cur)
    {
        control.style.cursor = "url("+cur+")";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you use CSS?  That seems like it would be the most straightforward way to do this.  Also, is this ASP Classic or ASP.NET?  Your question/tags are ambiguous.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, that's actually ASP .NET. In fact, when a control is clicked, I would like the cursor to take the ImageButton's ImageUrl. Consequently, if I create a css class for those controls with "cursor: url("mypicture.png");", the cursor's look will always be the same and will not depend of the control's ImageUrl anymore.
Howerver, if there's a way to change cursor's url directly in css it'd just be perfect !